# How to validate math formular string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, math

I have a textbox to input a mathematical formular inlcude `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`,`(,)`,`TRUNC`,`ROUND`,`POWER`,`MOD`,`SQRT`,`FLOOR`,`DECODE`. After user input a formula string, i want to validate this string but i don't know how ???
Please help me out.

Comment: Please give sample input and output..

Comment: Same thing as with XML: you cannot parse a recursive structure with a single regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't validate such expressions using regex. The nature of the regular expressions is so, that you never can validate matching parenthesis. Regex is simply to weak.

For more information why it is so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

In order to validate/parse or evaluate mathematical expressions you need a context free grammar parser. You can relatively simple generate one using one of parser generators. I would recommend

- JavaCC: https://javacc.java.net/
- Antlr: http://www.antlr.org/

Context free grammars: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42323/math-expression-solver). It shows some code for parsing such expressions and the answers give examples on how to alternatively use the scripting engine that ships with Java.